# How to update a child in an array in mongodb collection using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am a very beginner with mongodb/mongoose. I have this mongoose document:

```js
const MySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    minLength: 5,
    maxlength: 100,
    required: true
  },
  children: [{
    name: {
      type: String,
      minLength: 10,
      maxlength: 200,
      required: true
    },
  }],
}],
```

that saves a document like this:

```json
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("63a4bde8680e26987e8abd1f"),
  "name" : "parent 1",
  "children" : [{
      "name" : "child 1",
      "_id" : ObjectId("63a94a4a1baa3d5bfdc22fb4")
    },
    {
      "name" : "child 2",
      "_id" : ObjectId("63a94a4a1baa3d5bfdc22fb4")
    }
  ]
}
```

how can I update a single child given the objectId (ex: 63a94a4a1baa3d5bfdc22fb4) using mongoose?

I recall the parent but I don't kbnow how to update a single child element

```
let parent = await Manager.getParent(parentId);
  let documentToUpdate = {
    question: question,
    questionType: questionType,
    answers: answers
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [positional operator - `$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), like this:

```js
MyModel.updateOne({
  "name": "parent 1",
  "children._id": "63a94a4a1baa3d5bfdc22fb4"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "children.$.name": "new name"
  }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EtnpZK8tnyN)

Comment: ok but this is the mongodb shell, how can I do it using mongoose?

Comment: I updated my question. Can you try it again?